# Angular 2 ngDefaultControl

Tags: angular

I'm looping through list of items, and each item has an input with his own model.

I have the following code:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
    <md-input placeholder="Quantity" value="0" min="0" step="1" type="number"
        [(ngModel)]="items[i].amount" #amount
                  (ngModelChange)="calculateSubtotal($event)"
                  ngDefaultControl
                  >
        </md-input>
</div>
```

What happens is, if I will write the number "5" in one of the inputs, all of them will show it.

Since Rc.5, I had to put the `ngDefaultControl` because without it I get

```
EXCEPTION: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
  control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

  Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
  Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

Removing the **ngDefaultControl** and adding a name (like described in the error above) returns the following error:

```
EXCEPTION: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name
```

My input with a name looks like it:

```
<md-input placeholder="Quantity" value="0" min="0" step="1" type="number"
            [(ngModel)]="items[i].amount" [name]="items[i].amount" #amount
                      (ngModelChange)="calculateSubtotal($event)"
                      >
            </md-input>
```

I tried to add the `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}` expression, but It didnt work too.

Also tried to `name="coolName"` to check if it's my expression, and the error still remains!

Any help?

Comment: It would be helpful to get more code. How do you loop. How does `items` look like?

Comment: What happens if you implement one of the 2 suggestions instead of adding `ngDefaultControl`?

Comment: `items` are an array of items from my API, it's an array of objects with name, image, etc.. and I added the `amount` property is a new property I added on my angular2 client (as described in my code). It worked fine in previous Angular 2 versions

Comment: With or without the `ngDefaultControl`, the error is the same error described in my question

Comment: It would be great if you could replace "but It didnt work." by exact information what happened (exact error message or misbehavior).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I re-wrote my question to make it clear with any try/error I get

Comment: What is the reason that you use  [(ngModel)]="items[i].amount" and not  just [(ngModel)]="item.amount" ?

Comment: @PeterSalomonsen I'm really not sure why did I do that! Just changed to `item.amount`, but it seem have nothing to do with the error I get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declraing an input name worked it out. When I used `item.amount` the value was 0, changing it to `item.name` make it work fine....

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem. What fixed it for me was making sure that the name attribute on each md-input was unique. It had nothing to do with the ngDefaultControl.

Basically I had the following code:

`<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
    <md-input [(ngModel)]="items[i].amount" name="amount"></md-input>
</div>`

The ngModel in my controller had all the correct data but the view showed only the data from the last row repeated in every row. I changed my template to the following:

`<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
    <md-input [(ngModel)]="items[i].amount" name="{{'amount' + i}}"></md-input>
</div>`

Maybe not the prettiest way to solve it but it guarantees unique name attributes and fixed the problem.